# How to update query on button click without hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have a component with a button, input. I want to get information from graphql server and update the input information. But my code does not change the graphql query and I have the same result. Could you help me? I tried to find some information on tutorial - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/ but there is only useLazyQuery and I want to do it without hook.

```
function User() {
    let r = `query ~ first query`;

    function handleClick() {
        r = `query ~ updated query`;
    }


    return (
        <Query<UserDetails, Variables>
            query={gql([r])}>

            {({data}) => {
                let res = '';
                if (data && data.me && data.me.name) {
                    res += `${data.me.name} `;
                }

                return (
                    <span>
                        <form onSubmit={e => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                handleClick();}}>
                            <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
                            <input type="text" value={res}/>
                        </form>
                    </span>
                );
            }}
        </Query>
    );
}
```

Comment: @xadm I tried to use componentDidMount and state in parent component. But How to access state in child?

Comment: lifting state up  ... in react docs (basic section)

Comment: @xadm Thank you))))